# Unfortunately stopped when I click on items and open new fragments layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I read some articles and make a nav drawer and fragments.i want to when I click on items in nav drawer, open fragments layout. but when I click on my fragments, my app crashed and unfortunately has stopped.

Can any one tell me what do I wrong? or what should I do to resolve my problem?

This is my MainActivty.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView nvDrawer;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);


}

private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {

    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
}


private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;

        case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
            fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;

        case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
            fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;

        default:
            fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }

    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

This is my firstfragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public FirstFragment() {
}

public static FirstFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Comment: Post your error log. Also use `break;` statement while calling `fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;`
 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Call fragment by using below code;

```
 Fragment fragment = new TaskDiscussionFragment();
 FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);
 ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Listener which you are expecting in in `FirstFragment` in `MainActvity` and `override` the interface method like below,

`FirstFragment` is expecting `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in your `onAttach` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

}
```